# Unable to identify remote desktop in Blueprism

Tags: blueprism

I am trying to automate certain things in a remote desktop using surface migration techniques in blueprism.

I have to open Windows Remote Desktop and enter the login details, but i am unable to identify it in application modeller. After launching mstsc.exe using the application modeler the identify button disappears and turns back to launch and due to this i am unable to use region mode to identify or spy elements.

Any solutions for this?

[Snippet of the application modeller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xxa6v.png)

Comment: Do you run it as a windows application? If you do that I dont see why you should use Region Mode.

Comment: Yes, i am running it as windows application. I was trying this with different applications and saw the same thing happening with windows 10 version of calculator.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem creating 2 objects.
- Object one will execute "mstsc.exe"
- Object two will attach an existing mstsc.exe execution

So you have to launch mstsc.exe in your first object then go to the second one and attach it. If everything goes fine, you'll be able to use the application modeler in your second object and identify whatever you need to.

Example first object:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/du6xk.png)

Example second object:
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wIRI.png)

Comment: Thanks for the help, i will try this.

Comment: Why are you not installing blueprism on the same machine you are remoting into instead of doing surface?